# Trying to change a value in a vector bool

Tags: c++, vector, boolean

I'm reading Stroustrup PPP and while doing an exercise, I found this error.

### Why I can't change the value of a vector bool?

```cpp
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
  vector<bool> vecc(2, true);

  vecc[1] = true; // I can't do this, returns error.

  return 0;
}
```

The error:

`error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'bool&' to an rvalue of type 'bool' return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);`

Second, when I try with the int type, the problem does not occur.

```cpp
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main(){
  vector<int> vecc = {true, true};


  for(bool x : vecc) {cout<<x<<"\n";}

  vecc[1] = false; //ok

  for(bool x : vecc){cout<<x<<"\n";}
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
1
0
```

#### Edit:

Probably this is because I was using `#include "std_lib_facilities.h"`

[std_lib_facilities.h](https://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h)

Comment: The first snippet [works for me](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/afvrGvsYj). Is this your actual code?

Comment: `vector<bool>` is a weird-o. It's such a weird-o that [it gets its own documentation page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat could it depend on the C++ version?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It doesn't seem to. I've reopened the question, since I don't see how the nature of `vector<bool>` would prevent this from working.

Comment: On every C++ lang setting from 98 through 20, using both g++ and clang++, they *all* work.

Comment: @WhozCraig All of the c++ lang settings will still use the same STL and yours (and mine) are working fine. It must be some implementation problem in the STL, not a language problem.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it seems to be [std_lib_facilities.h](https://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h). I wasn't using #include vector; Thanks to you I was able to solve. 

I was only using #include "../../std_lib_facilities.h". Maybe was a conflicting or something

Comment: They ship a broken `vector`, it seems (in the sense that it doesn't support `bool`s). In the future, please post complete code, with all includes.

Comment: `enum class Bool : bool { False, True };` and `vector<Bool> vecc(2, Bool::True);` to sidestep the questionable `vector<bool>` specialization.

Comment: @Yuno `#include "std_lib_facilities.h"` -- The question I would have is this:  where did you get the idea to use this header, as no reputable C++ book or tutorial even mentions anything like this.  Every book / tutorial has `#include <vector>`, so it is a mystery as to why you skipped this and used this (obscure) header instead.

Comment: *as no reputable C++ book...* I can think of one. It ships with **Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++** and is used heavily in its examples.

Comment: @user4581301 Well, I guess it would be time for the book to come up with a newer edition that has the appropriate updates, if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm kind of surprised there wasn't a C++17 update. Maybe a C++20 revision is in the works. C++ Primer 6th edition is supposed to hit shelves later this year.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Because the book ask to use (temporarily).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std_lib_facilities.h defines the following helper template to add a bit of error checking helpful to folks beginning their programming careers:

```cpp
// trivially range-checked vector (no iterator checking):
template< class T> struct Vector : public std::vector<T> {
    using size_type = typename std::vector<T>::size_type;

/* #ifdef _MSC_VER
    // microsoft doesn't yet support C++11 inheriting constructors
    Vector() { }
    explicit Vector(size_type n) :std::vector<T>(n) {}
    Vector(size_type n, const T& v) :std::vector<T>(n, v) {}
    template <class I>
    Vector(I first, I last) : std::vector<T>(first, last) {}
    Vector(initializer_list<T> list) : std::vector<T>(list) {}
*/
    using std::vector<T>::vector;   // inheriting constructor

    T& operator[](unsigned int i) // rather than return at(i);
    {
        if (i<0 || this->size() <= i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
    }
    const T& operator[](unsigned int i) const
    {
        if (i<0 || this->size() <= i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::vector<T>::operator[](i);
    }
};
```

`T& operator[](unsigned int i)` and its `const` variant return a reference to `T` and in this case `T` is `bool`. To get the element it calls through to `std::vector`'s `operator[]` to do the grunt work.

Unfortunately `std::vector<bool>` is not a proper library container. Because it packs bits rather than storing `bool`s, it can't return a reference to a `bool` from the element access methods. It doesn't have any `bool`s to reference. [Instead it returns a groovy `reference` class](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.bool) that conceals the bit packing from sight and usually makes life a bit easier. Under most circumstances the element access  methods will behave exactly the same way as a regular `vector`.

But not this time. It's not returning a reference and it's not returning a reference to a `bool` so the simple pass-through fails to compile.

Common work arounds are to use a `std::vector` containing some small integer type or an `enum` or use a `std::deque<bool>` which can be used largely the same way and doesn't have a bit-backing specialization. If the size is known at compile time, consider using a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Comment: The other workaround is to use `std::deque<bool>`.  Then magically, everything works :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Stollen and added.

Comment: You should be returning `std::vector<T>::reference`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow That would solve the problem, but then you're taking up the responsibility for your edits in a third-party library. Often a coin-toss whether or not that's a good idea. You should pitch it to Bjarne for his next edition.

Comment: @user4581301 Or just drop the not so helpful helper class because it's broken and teaches people the wrong thing. Teach them to use `std::vector<T>::at()` right from the beginning. Unsafe interfaces should be left to the experts. *<rant>*

Answer (score 0):

The [standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) provides a specialization of std::vector for the type bool, which may be optimized for space efficiency. This stores bool as 1 bit saving you a lot of memory for large vectors.

The problem with that is that you can not return a reference to a bit so the standard library is supposed to return `reference` object wrapper around the bit that allows assignment. The object keeps a reference to the vector and the bit position you asked for and has an `operator=()` that calls `std::vector<bool>::assign()`.

The example code for this even has this:

```
std::vector<bool> is_prime(N, true);
is_prime[0] = is_prime[1] = false;
```

Only thing I can think of is that your compiler has an old version of the STL or a bad implementation that does have a vector specialization but without the wrapper reference object. Try

```
vecc.assign(1, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But wasn't the compiler. See the edit, I was using std_lib_facilities.h. When I use``#include <vector>`` the program run.